# MIT Kerberos with OpenLDAP backend - TLS ok when KDC started interactively but init script fails

Tags: debian, openldap, kerberos, tls

In DNS domain

```
domain.local.
```

there are two machines

```
host.domain.local. = 192.168.1.1
srv1.domain.local. = 192.168.1.2

host.domain.local. is KDC for Kerberos realm DOMAIN.LOCAL,
srv1.domain.local. is a KDC for Kerberos realm RC.DOMAIN.LOCAL.
```

There's an unidirectional trust between RC.DOMAIN.LOCAL and DOMAIN.LOCAL:

```
RC.DOMAIN.LOCAL ===trusts===> tickets from DOMAIN.LOCAL,
```

but not vice-versa.

The KDC for RC.DOMAIN.LOCAL on srv1 have been set up with an OpenLDAP- backend according to

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html

with its OpenLDAP backend on host.domain.local, reachable by

```
ldaps://host.domain.local:636.
```

There is also a local OpenLDAP installed (but diabled) on srv1, thus there exist local ldap.conf etc. on srv1 to be taken into consideration.

---

When I start the KDC on srv1 manually in a (srv1) root session

```
root@srv1:~# krb5kdc
```

everything works fine.

---

When I attempt to start the KDC on srv1 by the system init scripts

```
root@srv1:~# /etc/init.d/krb5-kdc start
```

or

```
root@srv1:~# service krb5-kdc start
```

a TLS dialog between the krb5kdc on srv1 and the slapd on host fails; the combined syslog is

```
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: slap_listener_activate(6): 
14:46:44 srv1 krb5kdc[3206]: krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm RC.DOMAIN.LOCAL - see log file for details
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: >>> slap_listener(ldaps://192.168.1.1:636/)
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: listen=6, new connection on 10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: added 10r (active) listener=(nil)
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: conn=1037 fd=10 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.1.2:38664 (IP=192.168.1.1:636)
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: select: listen=6 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: select: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: waked
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: select: listen=6 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on:
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]:  10r
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: 
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: read activity on 10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_get(10): got connid=1037
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_read(10): checking for input on id=1037
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_read(10): TLS accept failure error=-1 id=1037, closing
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_closing: readying conn=1037 sd=10 for close
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_close: conn=1037 sd=10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: removing 10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: slap_listener_activate(6): 
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: >>> slap_listener(ldaps://192.168.1.1:636/)
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: listen=6, new connection on 10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: added 10r (active) listener=(nil)
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: conn=1038 fd=10 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.1.2:38666 (IP=192.168.1.1:636)
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: select: listen=6 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: select: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: waked
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: select: listen=6 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
14:46:44 srv1 systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
14:46:44 srv1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kerberos 5 Key Distribution Center.
14:46:44 srv1 systemd[1]: Unit krb5-kdc.service entered failed state.
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: activity on:
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]:  10r
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: 
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: read activity on 10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_get(10): got connid=1038
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_read(10): checking for input on id=1038
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_read(10): TLS accept failure error=-1 id=1038, closing
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_closing: readying conn=1038 sd=10 for close
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: connection_close: conn=1038 sd=10
14:46:44 host.domain.local slapd[1778]: daemon: removing 10
```

---

The /etc/ldap/ldap.conf on srv1 is

```
rootdn "cn=admin,cn=config"
rootpw {SASL}admin@DOMAIN.LOCAL
BASE    dc=domain,dc=local
URI ldaps://127.0.0.1:636/ ldapi:///
TLS_CACERT /etc/ldap/ssl/cacert.pem
TLS_REQCERT allow
SASL_MECH EXTERNAL
```

thus that mostly refers to the srv1-local slapd, but it's, as far as applicable, on the successful manual krb5kdc start on srv1 overridden by the  effective

```
.ldaprc  for root@srv1: 

URI             ldaps://host.domain.local:636
TLS_REQCERT     demand
SASL_MECH       EXTERNAL
TLS_CACERT      /root/secret/cacert.pem
TLS_CERT        /root/secret/root.srv1.domain.local-cert.pem
TLS_KEY         /root/secret/private/root.srv1.domain.local-key.pem
```

and by the dbmodules section of /etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf on srv1

```
[dbmodules]
    LDAP = {
        db_library = kldap
    ldap_kdc_sasl_mech = EXTERNAL
    ldap_kdc_dn = cn=krb5kdc,dc=rc,dc=domain,dc=local
    ldap_kadmind_dn = cn=kadmind,dc=rc,dc=domain,dc=local
    ldap_service_password_file = /etc/krb5kdc/ldap_stash
    ldap_kerberos_container_dn = cn=realm,dc=rc,dc=domain,dc=local
    #ldap_servers = ldap://host.domain.local:389
    ldap_servers = ldaps://host.domain.local:636
    }


root@srv1:~# ldapwhoami
```

yields

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: cn=root.srv1.domain.local,ou=...
SASL SSF: 0
dn:cn=admin,cn=config
```

and

```
root@srv1:~# ldapsearch -b "" -s base -LLL supportedSASLMechanisms
```

yields

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: cn=root.srv1.domain.local,ou=...
SASL SSF: 0
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: EXTERNAL
```

srv1 runs with amd64 Debian 8 "jessie":

```
krb5-kdc-ldap     1.12.1+dfsg-19 
ldap-utils        2.4.40+dfsg-1+deb8u1
libaprutil1-ldap  1.5.4-1
libkldap4         4:4.14.2-2+b1
libldap-2.4-2     2.4.40+dfsg-1+deb8u1
```

The Debian-conformant point for additional KDC configuration is /etc/default/krb5-kdc:

```
# [...]
DAEMON_ARGS="-r RC.DOMAIN.LOCAL"
# LDAPNOINIT=1
# LDAPRC=.ldaprc
# LDAPTLS_REQCERT=demand
# #LDAPSASL_SECPROPS   none
#LDAPSASL_MECH=EXTERNAL
#LDAPTLS_CACERT=/root/secret/cacert.pem
#LDAPTLS_CERT=/root/secret/root.srv1.domain.local-cert.pem
#LDAPTLS_KEY=/root/secret/private/root.srv1.domain.local-key.pem
```

As you can see from that, I tried to manually rebuild a propoer TLS environment for the KDC startup script, but to no avail yet.

**So - why does the KDC work perfectly from an interactive root shell, but fails from the init script and what to do about the latter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the OpenLDAP-backed KDC simply needs a the CA certificate located

in a **valid** ssl certificate directory,

where it can find its server's keys and certs as well, e.g. `/etc/ssl` on my srv1 box; e.g. altering the TLS_CACERT entry in

```
/etc/ldap/ldap.conf
```

to

```
#[...]
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
#[...]
```

made the init script working.

That's not the only measure that would work, one could e.g. also try and set

```
[dbmodules]
    LDAP = {
        # [...]
        ldap_cert_path = ...
        # [...]
    }
```

in `/etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` (untested) or add

```
LDAPTLS_CACERT=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

to Debian's `/etc/default/krb5-kdc` (tested).